# SP foundation 2013 master page to HTML

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, master-page, css, html

How to convert the **master-page** to the **HTML**. I've made changes to CSS (which i want to use) and i found the only way to do so by adding it to the HTML conversion of the master page. I'm new to the Sharepoint so there might be a different way to do so, which i didn't found.
Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to Take a look at this link first:    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj822370(v=office.15).aspx#Understand

This is necessary to start with SharePoint master page.

As per your question I am unable to get your point but as far as I understood, you need to change the same on HTML page first, after that change will automatically reflected on master page file. You don't need to change directly on master page file when you have the html file.

If you find this as solution, mark this as answer. :)

Comment: My Q wasn't mby clear enough. Right now i'm using Sharepoint Foundation 2013. I need to do some changes to the design. In the full version of the Sharepoint 2013 you can use Design Manager to make a HTML file from the XXX.master, do some changes and link a CSS file to it (as far as i know the XXX.master shouldnt be edited and every change should be done to the HTML). But in Foundation version there is no Design Manager, so i'm looking for something similar (free to use) master page to HTML conversion.